# Use the same method across a list of mixed objects in C++

Tags: c++

Edit: Thanks for the input - I've realized this is far more obvious than I'd thought!

Lets say I have a number of classes, all of which inherit from one base class. Say we have `Shape`, `Circle` and `Square` inherit from it. The `Shape` class has a virtual method `getArea()`, which is then defined in `Circle` and `Square` .

I would like to create a list of circle and square objects, and then call the function `getArea()` on each object in the list in turn.

Is it possible to mix the `Square` and `Circle` classes into a single list object like this? If I do that, is it then possible to walk through objects in the list, and call the same named method in each class?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, keeping a list/vector of base class pointers is one of the most common usages of inheritance and polymorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `Shape` is a polymorphic base (i.e. it has one or more virtual functions, that derived classes can override) then it is possible.

For example;

```
  #include <vector>
  #include <memory>

   // definitions of Shape, Circle, Square, etc

  int main()
  {
      std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Shape>> shapes;

      shapes.push_back(new Circle);
      shapes.push_back(new Square);
      for (auto &s : shapes)
      {
           s->getArea();
      } 

       //   when shapes ceases to exist, so do the objects it contains
      return 0;
  }
```

It is also necessary that `Shape` has a virtual destructor in the above.

Note that `unique_ptr` is C++11 or later.   There are other smart pointers (like `shared_ptr`) you may wish to use instead, depending on your needs.

Comment: and `getArea()` is a `virtual` function, implemented accordingly for different `Shape`s such as `Square` and `Circle`

Comment: @Rishi - that was stated in the question, so I didn't bother to restate it.

Answer (score 0):

After I posted this question, I started to remember how C++ works!
I wrote up an example for myself for future reference - hopefully it proves handy to others!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

class Shape
{
    public:
        virtual unsigned int getArea() = 0;
};

class Circle: public Shape
{
    public:
        unsigned int getArea(){
            return M_PI * radius * radius;
        }
        int getPerimeter(){
            return 2 * M_PI * radius;
        }
    private:
        unsigned int radius = 5;
};

class Square: public Shape
{
    public:
        unsigned int getArea(){
            return side*side;
        }
    private:
        unsigned int side = 5;
};

int main(void)
{
    Circle circle1, circle2;
    Square square1, square2;
    Shape *shapes[] = {&circle1, &square1, &circle2, &square2};
    int idx;

    std::cout << "Hello!" << std::endl;

    for(idx = 0; idx < 4; idx++){
        std::cout << "Shape " << idx << " area is: "
            << shapes[idx]->getArea() << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Circle1's perimeter is: "
        << circle1.getPerimeter() << std::endl;
}
```